# Log website using banner

Tags: php

I'm trying to log the websites who are using my banner on their website.. So I started like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM websites WHERE url = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] . "'" )) {
    if($result->num_rows !== 0) {
        echo "I already know this website contains my banner...!";
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO websites VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] . "', NOW())";
        $db->query($query);
        echo "Hey, this is a new website who placed my banner! Let's add them to my database...";
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

I'll replace the `echo`'s by serving a jpg or png file so it will actually display the banner. But, the remote_address is always empty, is their any other way to save the website url to my database of the website where the banner has been placed? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking at the referrer and not the REMOTE_HOST. REMOTE_HOST will contain the hostname of the clients browser, *NOT* the server where the banner code is placed. HTTP_REFERER is what you're looking for.

Comment: No the `REFERER` is where the clicked link came from. There is NO way to find out the site where a banner is placed.

Comment: @BartFriederichs just wording.. The banner is clearly hosted on OPs server, what he wants to know is where the code *requesting* the banner is hosted (ie. where the img tag is place). Only the referrer will contain said info.

Comment: I changed my wording. Still it won't work. From the PHP site (emphasis mine): "The address of the page (if any) **which referred the user agent to the current page**. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."

Comment: Indeed, we can both agree that you can never trust user input and in all public facing HTTP services all input is user input including the headers, *but* that is not the question here. So yes relying on the referrer is the *best* option even though not 100% accurate, it will be close. This is extremely common practice in the world of user tracking, something I make a living off of ;)

Comment: This lead me to look into it a little more, and this I didn't know: "The referer for an image, for example, is generally the HTML page on which it is to be displayed.". I thought it only worked for `<a>` links. I learned something today.

Comment: Yes exactly @BartFriederichs! This is the reason why the so many  commercial websites will embed dozens of 1x1 px transparent GIFs which point to 3rd party tracking services ;) We also use this for conversion tracking for example when we place custom img tags on the "Thank you" page after an online purchase, in which case we of course use what you mentioned above: unique IDs for each img. We even refer to the practice as "pixeling users" ^^

Comment: Just 1 last comment: open your firebug/chrome tools and see the network tag after refreshing this very page then sort by "type" to see the GIFs being requested because even SO uses the technique! I just now got pixeled by OpenX (huge RTB provider for advertisement), google analytics, and fbcdn.com.. facebook :)

Comment: I used the referrer and it works like a charm till now, I'll test for a while using unique keys to look if there will be any difference between the referrer technique and using a unique key for each site. Thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 2):

This will not work like that. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` is the [address of the client](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) viewing the site, not the site it is embedded in. There is no way to find out where your banner is hosted. The user agent (browser) will just request the banner from your server.

You should ask the people that are embedding your banners in their site to add some kind of key. Without a key, you serve nothing, with a key, you know who your client is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove addrress can be empty indeed. Maybe you can have a look at the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`instead and do a lookup yourself. Another option is to combine those things.

Also keep in mind that this data can be spoofed by the other side of the line.